# How to narrow this type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

The following sample code does not pass the type check. I would like to find a way to make it pass without `as` casting, if possible.

```
type SupportedHandlerType = string | number | Date
type Handler<T> = (data: T[]) => void

function example<T extends SupportedHandlerType>(data: T[]) {
  const handler = getHandler(data)
  handler(data)
}

function stringHandler(data: string[]) {

}

function numberHandler(data: number[]) {
    
}

function dateHandler(data: Date[]) {
    
}

function getHandler<T>(data: T[]): Handler<T> {
    const first = data[0]
    if (typeof first == 'string') {
        return stringHandler // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'
    }
    if (typeof first == 'number') {
        return numberHandler // another error here
    }
    return dateHandler // and here
}
```

My real life version is much more complicated, but this simple piece show cases the problem I have: I have a few types forming a union (`SupportedHandlerType`), and the generic function is called with one of those. I have a `getHandler()`, which dynamically looks at the types to determine which one it is and returns the appropriate handler function, which has a dedicated type instead of `T`.

Is there a way to somehow narrow the types so that I don't get errors such as `Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'`?

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wjQK7W)

Comment: How does your original code even function? You are checking if the type of an array is a string or number? Did you mean to check `data[0]` or `first` instead?

Comment: Yes, sorry! Exactly so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays lose their typing once they are transpiled to javascript. Meaning, that you can't be sure what the type of an array is, except if you iterate through them and check the value of each element.

That's why I would add these 2 functions.

```
function isArrayOfStrings(value: unknown): value is string[] {
  return Array.isArray(value) && value.every(item => typeof item === "string");
}

function isArrayOfNumbers(value: unknown): value is number[] {
  return Array.isArray(value) && value.every(item => typeof item === "number");
}
```

More importantly, notice the return type of these functions. These kind of functions are sometimes called "type-guards". the `... is ...` return-value-type indicates that when the function returns true, this also means that we can conclude that the input variable was of a certain type.

Finally, I changed something to the `T` generic. You can make them `extend` something. By doing so, I simplified the generics and indicated that the input `T` should always be an array.

```
type Handler<T extends any[]> = (data: T) => void

function getHandler<T extends any[]>(data: T): Handler<T> {
  if (isArrayOfStrings(data)) {
    return stringHandler;
  }
  if (isArrayOfNumbers(data)) {
    return numberHandler;
  }
  return dateHandler;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to loop through the entire arrays, you could simplify the `isArrayOf...` functions by just checking the type of the first element.

#### Additional Note:

Please note that the following code is in no way affected.

```
type SupportedHandlerType = string | number | Date
function example<T extends SupportedHandlerType>(data: T[]) {
  const handler = getHandler(data)
  handler(data)
}
```

The `T` in the function above is a different `T` than the one of the other functions, which I admit can be confusing. Let me try to clarify that:

- `data` can be a `string[]` in the context of this function. Locally here `T[]` is `string[]` in that case.
- At the same time `data` then also complies to the requirements of `getHandler(data)`. Because `string[]` also complies to the `T` of `getHandler`, where `T is string[]`.

So, there are 2 different `T`'s at play.
Or if that gets you confused, rename the `T` to `U` only for this part of the code.

```
type SupportedHandlerType = string | number | Date
function example<U extends SupportedHandlerType>(data: U[]) {
  const handler = getHandler(data)
  handler(data)
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that now T can be of any array type. I want it to be of `SupportedHandlerType` type. Otherwise you could pass any arrays not just the few types of arrays I want.

Comment: @KaiSellgren If I'm not mistaken, that's not the case. I added a part to clarify this.

Comment: One issue with this is that now the `getHandler()` can return any type of function that takes an array because of the `any[]`. So, it could return a function that takes `RegExp[]` even though that's not one of the supported types.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to how you are declaring the handler functions. You have to stick to the same structure declared in `type Handler`

```
type SupportedHandlerType = string | number | Date
type Handler<T> = (data: T[]) => void

function example<T extends SupportedHandlerType>(data: T[]) {
  const handler = getHandler(data)
  handler(data)
}

function stringHandler<T = string>(data: T[]) {

}

function numberHandler<T = number>(data: T[]) {
    
}

function dateHandler<T = Date>(data: T[]) {
    
}

function getHandler<T>(data: T[]): Handler<T> {
    const first = data[0]
    if (typeof data == 'string') {
        return stringHandler // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'
    }
    if (typeof data == 'number') {
        return numberHandler // another error here
    }
    return dateHandler // and here
}
```

Comment: One problem with this is that the handler functions now take T[] as a parameter even though we have dedicated handlers for different types. Now the handler needs to check the T type.